# HTML anchor href without scheme

Tags: html, anchor, href

When I specify a url in href, it auto prefixes the scheme

```
<a href="mysite/test.html">link</a>
```

Points to http://mysite/test.html

I pull my docker images using

```
docker pull mysite/path/to/repo:tagname
```

I want to specify the docker link in href attribute
But the browser considers below path as relative path

```
<a href="mysite/path/to/repo:tagname"></a>
```

If I prefix it with //, it is no longer a relative path, but still prefixes the scheme

```
<a href="//mysite/path/to/repo:tagname"></a>
```

How can I make the browser point it exactly to mysite/path/to/repo:tagname?

My usecase is:
When user right clicks on it, and clicks copy link address, only the part "mysite/path/to/repo:tagname" should be copied to clipboard, so that user can use it on commandline

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve with the link?

Comment: when user right clicks on it, and clicks copy link address, only the part "mysite/path/to/repo:tagname" should be copied to clipboard, so that user can use it on commandline

Comment: in that case you need to implement some javascript logic, which will intercept user's mouse click. Or even better, make a `copy to clipboard` button and put to clipboard whatever you want :)

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal you must update question